# FacesMessages in MyFacesServlet Wrapper

Tags: java, jsf

I throw NullPointerException in a java bean and catch the exception in FacesServletWrapper.
in FacesServletWrapper I gets always only ServletException.

1. how can I catch the specific exception that I throw?
2. How can I continue from where I throws the exception?

in my bean:

```
 public String getSize() {  
  try {
   Object object = null;
   object.equals("");

  } catch (Exception e) {
   throw new NullPointerException();
  }


 }
```

my servlet:

```
 public class FacesServletWrapper extends MyFacesServlet {

 public static final String CONFIG_FILES_ATTR = "javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES";
 public static final String LIFECYCLE_ID_ATTR = "javax.faces.LIFECYCLE_ID";

 private ServletConfig servletConfig;
 private FacesContextFactory facesContextFactory;
 private Lifecycle lifecycle;

 @Override
 public void service(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
  FacesContext facesContext = facesContextFactory.getFacesContext(servletConfig.getServletContext(), request, response, (javax.faces.lifecycle.Lifecycle) lifecycle);
  try {
   super.service(request, response);
  } catch (Throwable e) {
   Locale locale = (Locale) facesContext.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get(Constants.LOCALE);
   ServletContext context = servletConfig.getServletContext();
   RequestDispatcher dispatcher = context.getRequestDispatcher("/errors/error.jsf");

   if (e instanceof NullPointerException) {
                        //here I catch  only ServletException
    String error = ResourceUtil.getMessage("Login_failed", locale);
    facesContext.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("error", error);
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect(((HttpServletRequest) request).getContextPath() + "/errors/error.jsf");
   } 
  }

 }

 public void destroy() {
  servletConfig = null;
  facesContextFactory = null;
  lifecycle = null;
 }

 public ServletConfig getServletConfig() {
  return servletConfig;
 }

 private String getLifecycleId() {
  String lifecycleId = servletConfig.getServletContext().getInitParameter(LIFECYCLE_ID_ATTR);
  return lifecycleId != null ? lifecycleId : LifecycleFactory.DEFAULT_LIFECYCLE;
 }

 @Override
 public void init(ServletConfig servletConfig) throws ServletException {
  super.init(servletConfig);
  this.servletConfig = servletConfig;
  facesContextFactory = (FacesContextFactory) FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.FACES_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
  LifecycleFactory lifecycleFactory = (LifecycleFactory) FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.LIFECYCLE_FACTORY);
  lifecycle = (Lifecycle) lifecycleFactory.getLifecycle(getLifecycleId());
 }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a stack trace so we could see where it gets thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `FacesServlet#service()` here:

```
try {
    super.service(request, response);
} catch (Throwable e) {
    // ...
}
```

Here's an extract from [its javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/faces/webapp/FacesServlet.html#service%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) to learn what kind of exception it may throw:

> If a `FacesException` is thrown in either case, extract the cause from the `FacesException`. If the cause is `null` extract the message from the `FacesException`, put it inside of a new `ServletException` instance, and pass the `FacesException` instance as the root cause, then rethrow the `ServletException` instance. If the cause is an instance of `ServletException`, rethrow the cause. If the cause is an instance of `IOException`, rethrow the cause. Otherwise, create a new `ServletException` instance, passing the message from the cause, as the first argument, and the cause itself as the second argument.

In other words, it will **always** throw either `ServletException` or `IOException`. You need to use [`Throwable#getCause()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getCause%28%29) to extract the desired cause from the catched `ServletException` and then determine it further. E.g.

```
if (e.getCause() instanceof NullPointerException) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hi!
I realized that i had to go through 4 e.getCause() like this:
e.getCause().getCause().getCause().getCause().
I will probably need to loop until i get a null result and the previous one will be my exception.

Do you have an answer regarding my second question - 
How can I continue from where I throws the exception? I mean, I would like to catch the exception and return to the user's code in the bean as if it's a regular try{}catch{} in the bean?